# How to check for MouseEvents in the queue

Tags: java, caching, buffer, mouseevent

I made a program for viewing a fractal, and when the user clicks, the program recalculates and zooms. But if the user clicks again while the program processes the first zoom, I want it to stop, and skip straight to the second zoom. However, since the program is busy calculating, the Mouse Event never gets detected by the GUI. How can I make sure the mouse event is processed even if the application is busy.

Comment: Threading will be helpful in this type of case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). They are used for performing background tasks that are triggered by GUI events (such as pressing a button).

You would make your SwingWorker cancellable (presumably it does some sort of looping) and if a new task is submitted, cancel the running one, and start the next one.

Comment: +1, competitor voting! This sounds more relevant. however fundamentally this must be doing same thing what we do manually with threads :)

Comment: This is about identical to what I did. I used a runnable thread that cancelled when a boolean was set to false. Probably the same mechanism used by SwingWorker internally. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As I said in above comment normally what you are looking for is known as threading. this below link will give you information regarding it.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Threading will let your UI thread work while in background some other thread is busy calculating.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your input, but I found another solution: I created a runnable to generate the new fractal, which runs in a loop that terminates when a certain boolean is made false. When the gui detects a mouse click, it sets that boolean to false and runs the calculating thread again with the new zoom coordinates.

Comment: I tried to stay away from the Swing specific threading tools because Swing threading has not worked very well for me in the past.